# unable to resolve host hp cloud

Tags: openstack, hp-cloud-services

With the help of open stack commands I have made instance in HP cloud. After creating instance and associating with floating IP when I try to run lamp commands on instance means try to install mysql, apache etc on instance then I am getting error

```
unable to resolve host "instance_name"
```

I have implemented commands from following link.

```
http://docs.openstack.org/cli-reference/content/novaclient_commands.html
```

and Link of HP account https://horizon.hpcloud.com/

what can be the error and possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

edit

/etc/hosts

append:

```
127.0.0.1     <instance name>
```